# Get JSON Array of Objects

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I've been trying to get Array of Objects, but all I'm ending up getting only Objects.

The Table Definition was made by other Developers. This is the reference.

```
CREATE TABLE FLOW_REQUEST
   (REQID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    REQ_MESSAGE CLOB,
    PRIMARY_KEYS VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    STATUS VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT FLOW_REQUEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (REQID, PRIMARY_KEYS)
   ) TABLESPACE ${ts_data};
```

Below is the sample Oracle query written.
`t1` data is mapped from already created data.

```
SELECT t1.REQID  AS "requestDetail.reqId",
  t1.PRIMARY_KEYS   AS "requestDetail.pk",
  t1.ENTITY_NAME    AS "requestDetail.entityName",
  t1.STATUS         AS "requestDetail.stage",
                                                         
  t2.id             AS "id",
  t2.div            AS "div",
                                                                 
  t2.code           AS "group.code",
  t2.type           AS "group.type",
  t2.task1          AS "group.animalGroup.task1",
  t2.task2          AS "group.animalGroup.task2" 
                                                                
FROM FLOW_REQUEST t1
JOIN json_table(t1.REQ_MESSAGE,'$.animals' columns(         
  id            PATH '$.id',                                 
  div           PATH '$.div',

NESTED PATH '$.group[*]' COLUMNS (
  code          PATH '$.group.code',                         
  type          PATH '$.group.type',
  task1         PATH '$.group.animalGroup.task1',
  task2         PATH '$.group.animalGroup.task2'
  ))) t2
ON t1.PRIMARY_KEYS = t2.id
WHERE t1.ENTITY_NAME ='ANIMALS'
AND t1.STATUS        ='DRAFT'
```

**Here's the JSON Response I'm getting the "Group" as an Object**

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "requestDetail": {
                "reqId": "1",
                "pk": "1",
                "entityName": "ANIMALS",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "type": "animal",
            "group": {
                "code": "A1",
                "animalGroup": {
                    "task1": "eats",
                    "task2": "sleep"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected "Group" to be an Array**

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "requestDetail": {
                "reqId": "1",
                "pk": "1",
                "entityName": "ANIMALS",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "type": "animal",
            "group": [{
                "code": "A1",
                "animalGroup": {
                    "task1": "eats",
                    "task2": "sleep"
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the table definition and some sample data from `FLOW_REQUEST`?

Comment: Yes, added in the Description.